# How to make a Sticky navbar align its text center?

Tags: html, css

I made a sticky navbar and I'm trying to center the menu and for some reason, I can't at all, it's driving me nuts. I can't figure out why and I have tried a lot of answers, none work.

HTML code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Restaurant Titanic</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="indexC.css">
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="menu-list">
        <li><a href="">Acasa</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Acasa</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Acasa</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Acasa</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Acasa</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS code here

```
body{
    background-image: url("");
}

.navbar{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 0;         
}

.menu-list{
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.menu-list li {
    display: inline-block;
}

h1{
    color: white;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Comment: If you could put the code into Code Sandbox https://codesandbox.io/ It would be easier for people to help you debug :)

Comment: Is this reproduceable without `indexC.css`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code

```css
        body{
            background-image: url("");
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .navbar{
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #777;
            position: sticky;
            position: -webkit-sticky;
            top: 0;    
            padding: 15px;    
        }
        .menu-list{
            text-decoration: none;
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .menu-list li {
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .menu-list li a {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0 30px;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-size: 20px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .main p {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 30px;
            color: #333333;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: 500;
        }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
        <ul class="menu-list">
            <li><a href="">Acasa</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Acasa</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Acasa</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Acasa</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Acasa</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="main">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean laoreet tempus diam id varius. Curabitur quis placerat quam, sit amet consectetur odio. Aliquam mollis ac arcu sed viverra. Fusce et augue felis. Phasellus consequat ipsum sem, sit amet volutpat tortor ornare sit amet. Aliquam leo ante, sodales non faucibus sollicitudin, cursus sed lacus. Donec at finibus magna. Etiam porttitor, mi eget luctus viverra, lacus elit rhoncus nisl, quis pulvinar mauris purus eget lorem. In et nibh vitae tortor venenatis eleifend vitae quis turpis. Integer vestibulum nisi quam, varius commodo lacus lacinia vitae. Ut eget imperdiet eros, eget consectetur nulla. Nam nec semper est. Pellentesque scelerisque quam vel arcu tempus, sit amet mattis nulla luctus. Proin eu diam a justo accumsan dignissim vel eu elit. Mauris semper convallis massa eu ultrices.</p>
        <p>Fusce quis nisl ac urna dignissim volutpat. Donec sed felis tincidunt, ornare orci eget, lacinia nunc. Quisque a lacus vel est ornare dignissim pretium quis neque. Mauris non velit et est laoreet laoreet. Aliquam feugiat non quam sit amet consequat. Proin a dolor tempor, pharetra arcu id, ullamcorper dolor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Phasellus fringilla dictum diam a varius. Vestibulum tempus pellentesque sem sit amet lobortis. Integer eu purus non erat feugiat cursus eu eget tortor. Mauris luctus, elit eu porta fermentum, ipsum neque pellentesque nunc, et mattis orci sem lacinia est. Sed eget est sed augue euismod aliquet. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
        <p>Ut eu felis eget erat lobortis fringilla ut quis libero. Curabitur in tortor mattis, consectetur ex a, interdum quam. Nullam luctus neque eget felis tristique, vitae posuere est rhoncus. Morbi id imperdiet lorem. Nulla porttitor posuere sapien ac condimentum. Nam ut est et ex suscipit finibus ac at tortor. Proin augue risus, gravida vitae lacus non, consectetur pharetra tortor. Sed tristique pretium elit ut imperdiet. Morbi tincidunt mattis justo, quis blandit sem imperdiet elementum. Aenean varius molestie sapien quis viverra. Aliquam convallis efficitur erat. Aliquam convallis id leo eu ultricies. Etiam placerat odio ac placerat congue. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer vitae ipsum ut massa tempor commodo sed id odio. Nunc semper pellentesque augue non ornare.</p>
        <p>Nam sit amet eros risus. Nam arcu lectus, tincidunt quis fringilla eget, eleifend id felis. Duis at suscipit elit. Nunc tellus velit, viverra id urna vitae, scelerisque congue diam. Donec a nibh id nisi blandit tincidunt at at diam. Pellentesque accumsan diam turpis, hendrerit dapibus dolor finibus quis. Vivamus vulputate scelerisque enim, vitae rhoncus velit facilisis sed. Mauris laoreet eu eros sit amet auctor. Donec auctor molestie blandit.</p>
        <p>Proin pretium nibh tortor, aliquam accumsan massa porttitor luctus. Donec facilisis nisi sit amet commodo egestas. Aenean quis hendrerit quam. Nam ut tellus lorem. Mauris sed rhoncus purus, eu tincidunt orci. Aliquam suscipit justo non laoreet ullamcorper. Morbi faucibus nisi vitae velit egestas posuere. Nam porta convallis diam non dignissim. Suspendisse est nisi, tincidunt sed ullamcorper at, facilisis sit amet nisl. Donec a enim non tellus posuere tincidunt. Curabitur a metus sagittis, commodo urna sit amet, efficitur ipsum. In sed diam pellentesque, feugiat metus sed, gravida orci. Cras tempus pellentesque euismod. Etiam sollicitudin lectus odio, eget vestibulum justo vestibulum et. Integer posuere feugiat neque, sed aliquam felis lobortis et.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean laoreet tempus diam id varius. Curabitur quis placerat quam, sit amet consectetur odio. Aliquam mollis ac arcu sed viverra. Fusce et augue felis. Phasellus consequat ipsum sem, sit amet volutpat tortor ornare sit amet. Aliquam leo ante, sodales non faucibus sollicitudin, cursus sed lacus. Donec at finibus magna. Etiam porttitor, mi eget luctus viverra, lacus elit rhoncus nisl, quis pulvinar mauris purus eget lorem. In et nibh vitae tortor venenatis eleifend vitae quis turpis. Integer vestibulum nisi quam, varius commodo lacus lacinia vitae. Ut eget imperdiet eros, eget consectetur nulla. Nam nec semper est. Pellentesque scelerisque quam vel arcu tempus, sit amet mattis nulla luctus. Proin eu diam a justo accumsan dignissim vel eu elit. Mauris semper convallis massa eu ultrices.</p>
        <p>Fusce quis nisl ac urna dignissim volutpat. Donec sed felis tincidunt, ornare orci eget, lacinia nunc. Quisque a lacus vel est ornare dignissim pretium quis neque. Mauris non velit et est laoreet laoreet. Aliquam feugiat non quam sit amet consequat. Proin a dolor tempor, pharetra arcu id, ullamcorper dolor. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Phasellus fringilla dictum diam a varius. Vestibulum tempus pellentesque sem sit amet lobortis. Integer eu purus non erat feugiat cursus eu eget tortor. Mauris luctus, elit eu porta fermentum, ipsum neque pellentesque nunc, et mattis orci sem lacinia est. Sed eget est sed augue euismod aliquet. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
        <p>Ut eu felis eget erat lobortis fringilla ut quis libero. Curabitur in tortor mattis, consectetur ex a, interdum quam. Nullam luctus neque eget felis tristique, vitae posuere est rhoncus. Morbi id imperdiet lorem. Nulla porttitor posuere sapien ac condimentum. Nam ut est et ex suscipit finibus ac at tortor. Proin augue risus, gravida vitae lacus non, consectetur pharetra tortor. Sed tristique pretium elit ut imperdiet. Morbi tincidunt mattis justo, quis blandit sem imperdiet elementum. Aenean varius molestie sapien quis viverra. Aliquam convallis efficitur erat. Aliquam convallis id leo eu ultricies. Etiam placerat odio ac placerat congue. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer vitae ipsum ut massa tempor commodo sed id odio. Nunc semper pellentesque augue non ornare.</p>
        <p>Nam sit amet eros risus. Nam arcu lectus, tincidunt quis fringilla eget, eleifend id felis. Duis at suscipit elit. Nunc tellus velit, viverra id urna vitae, scelerisque congue diam. Donec a nibh id nisi blandit tincidunt at at diam. Pellentesque accumsan diam turpis, hendrerit dapibus dolor finibus quis. Vivamus vulputate scelerisque enim, vitae rhoncus velit facilisis sed. Mauris laoreet eu eros sit amet auctor. Donec auctor molestie blandit.</p>
        <p>Proin pretium nibh tortor, aliquam accumsan massa porttitor luctus. Donec facilisis nisi sit amet commodo egestas. Aenean quis hendrerit quam. Nam ut tellus lorem. Mauris sed rhoncus purus, eu tincidunt orci. Aliquam suscipit justo non laoreet ullamcorper. Morbi faucibus nisi vitae velit egestas posuere. Nam porta convallis diam non dignissim. Suspendisse est nisi, tincidunt sed ullamcorper at, facilisis sit amet nisl. Donec a enim non tellus posuere tincidunt. Curabitur a metus sagittis, commodo urna sit amet, efficitur ipsum. In sed diam pellentesque, feugiat metus sed, gravida orci. Cras tempus pellentesque euismod. Etiam sollicitudin lectus odio, eget vestibulum justo vestibulum et. Integer posuere feugiat neque, sed aliquam felis lobortis et.</p>
    </div>
```